# What is the best practice to control multiple views?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have this view in the storyboard:
[image: view consist of fixed controls and controls that changes according to the type of controller]

as you can see there are some fixed controls, and others that change according to the type of screen. 
What do you think is better?

1- Same view controller for multiple screens. (more code to control views)

2- Add all controls in the same screen, then hiding and showing them by code? (messy code)

3- View controller for each screen. (replicated code)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the word "window", which can lead to different interpretations of what you are trying to say. Use the word "screen", or "section of the screen". In this case, I would use a container of `UIViewControllers`. To communicate between then, use `KVO` or `NSNotificationCenter` (most probably the second one). Also make sure to not have the data source directly on the `UIViewController` (like an array or a dictionary). Keep the Data Source somewhere else, where all the `UIViewController`s (or any class) can easily access.  You could go with a Singleton.

Putting the Data Source away, and not directly on the `UIViewController`, gives you more flexibility over your code. If you ever need to use a new `UIViewController`, nothing is changed, he can still request resources from the same point. So keep that in mind.

---

**Edit 1**

> The data source also is inside the view controller, there is no
>   interaction between screens, it's the same screen but some controls
>   changes according to the type of it, what do you think I have to do
>   now?

The problem with this kind of approach is that if you need, for some reason to add a new `UIViewController`, that also use the same data source, what do you do now? I always try to decouple as much as possible the `UIViewController` from the Data Source. Otherwise you might have problems in the future, if the application changes (client's needs change). Again, moving the Data Source to a proper class, and use a Singleton to access it.

```
UIViewController <=> Singleton <=> Data Source
```

> So now you suggest to make multiple view controllers with multiple screens?

I suggest a `UIViewController` to act as a container for the others `UIViewControllers`. For me it makes more sense to compose the Screen as I go, than doing everything in one place.

Comment: Currently all views have the same view controller, they are all have outlets connected to the same view controller.
The data source also is inside the view controller, there is no interaction between screens, it's the same screen but some controls changes according to the type of it, what do you think I have to do now?

Comment: It's a possibility, although I prefer to `divide to conquer`.

Comment: BTW, data source is not the problem because all screens interacts with data source the same, so now you suggest to make multiple view controllers with multiple screens?

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitly go with no 3. This approach is most flexible! And it is clean => good to maintain